SQL - IN operator still working even if the field is not existing in the table being compared on. how is this possible?
Here I have two tables TB1, and TB2.
CREATE TABLE TB2(
COL1 NUMBER,
COL2 VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE TB1(
COL1 NUMBER,
COL2 VARCHAR(10),
COL3 NUMBER,
COL4 VARCHAR(10)
);

Containing the values below.
TB1
COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4
1   A   1   A
2   B   2   B

TB2
COL1    COL2
1   A

The below statement is working without an error even though COL3 is not existing in TB2.how is this possible?
SELECT * FROM TB1
WHERE COL3 IN (
  SELECT COL3 
  FROM TB2
  );

On the other hand when I'm using EXISTS, it returns an error.
SELECT * FROM TB1
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 
  FROM TB2
  WHERE TB1.COL3 = TB2.COL3
  );

How are they different?

Tip of today: qualify all columns. Just like TB1.COL3 instead of just COL3.

The subquery has access to its outer query tables (and columns).

SELECT COL3 FROM TB2 in your example is equivalent to SELECT TB1.COL3 FROM TB2 in case COL3 isn't defined on TB2. Always qualify your identifiers.

In the IN query, COL3 is not local to the inner scope but to the outer scope.

The IN query you are using is the same as:
SELECT *
FROM   TB1
WHERE  TB1.COL3 IN (
  SELECT TB1.COL3 
  FROM   TB2
);

Where the COL3 value is from TB1 in the outer scope and not TB2 in the local scope to the sub-query.
The equivalent EXISTS query would be:
SELECT *
FROM   TB1
WHERE  EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 
  FROM   TB2
  WHERE  TB1.COL3 = TB1.COL3
);


If you wanted an equivalent to your EXISTS query then:
SELECT *
FROM   TB1
WHERE  TB1.COL3 IN (
  SELECT TB2.COL3 
  FROM   TB2
);

(Which will give a syntax error as TB2 does not have a COL3 column.)
